# How to remove 'XXX$1.class' from git?

Tags: git, github

This is what I've tried:

[image: $1.class]

I also couldn't figure out how to remove it directly on github...

Comment: The commands are a little hard to read in your picture, is it possible to add just the terminal output as text in your question instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do a `git rm target/classes/test/java/NewTest$1.class`. You can also do `git add -A` which will stage deletes as well. You may need to do `git add -A :/` if on a newer version of git.

From there do a commit as usual `git commit -m "deleted file..."`, then `git push origin master` will delete it on github as well (assuming you're on the master branch).

Be sure to add `*.class` to your .gitignore file.

Comment: `git rm target/classes/test/java/NewTest$1.class` didn't work. But `git add -A` worked.

Comment: I did add it to .gitignore prior to my attempts. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has been answered already, but here's another solution:
Try escaping the dollar sign, for example, `git rm file\$1.class` if the file is `file$1.class`. That worked for me.